# How to remove Linefeed (LF) from first row in a text file using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, linefeed

I needed a script to remove the linefeed from the first row of a text file.

Other - similar topics I've researched were confusing, and had many irrelevant or misleading responses,

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need the first line, reading with set /p is simpler than a FOR/F loop.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p line= < source_file.txt
<nul set /p ".=!line!" > outputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

the way I used to get the **first row** (**NOTE: i have not tested if this also removes other hidden chars, but I was advised it does- like CR, so please be aware**) content and also remove the linefeed(=LF character) on Windows-command prompt/batch file/CMD/command is:

```
  for /F "delims=" %%i in (source_file.txt) do (  
      <nul (set/p z=%%i) >outputfile.txt
      goto BREAK1
    )
    :BREAK1
```

Immidiately Under **:BREAK1** row, you continue working on with a LineFeed free outputfile.txt

(Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.win2000.cmdprompt.admin/CHS0gwjZQDA/L85IIcFcLgkJ)

Comment: Yes, but that will remove the newline character as well.

Comment: @SomethingDark  yeah, that was the purpose of "How to remove Linefeed (LF)" .  I was aiming to remove the newline (A.k.a LF/ Line Feed)

Comment: I meant carriage return... no idea why I said line feed.

Comment: @SomethingDark  lol.  Thanks, i'm adding a comment that this also has potential to remove other hidden characters, not just the linefeed